# GeoServer WFS-T - Tracing features

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t, tracing

I'm setting up a web map with the ability to edit a polygon.

I'd like to be able to trace the outline of geometry from a separate layer and copy this to my editable layer. Is this possible with a WFS-T in GeoServer?

I'm aware that you can snap to another layer but what I'm looking for is to be able to completely trace another polygons outline.

Answer (score 1):

Tracing another layer would be a function of the client not the server. You could request the vector outline of the other polygon and use that as a basis for the polygon you sent to GeoServer as a WFS-T request.

I have provided similar capabilities to thin clients by using a WPS process to do the lookup.